# Learning aggressive driving behavior - Android Application

Tags: android, logic, artificial-intelligence, sensors, android-sensors

I am beginner therefore **please please please** help me out.
I am developing an android app which will learn the aggressive behavior of the driver and when learned it will rate a driver accordingly.
I have fixed the **acceleration** and **deceleration** values, whenever exceeded, reported as a wrong action. But **turns** are the tricky part.
Up-til i have implemented, i get the location where driver starts taking turn and where the turn is completed, the degree of turn taken too. Degree of turn will help me categorize type of turn *(U-Turn or Simple)*. Plus i can get speed of entering and exiting the turn. It will help me evaluate the turn taken.

- But the problem are the long curved roads, how can i handle them?
- Or how can i handle sharp turn during the smooth curve?
- Or what should i do to handle these both situations?

.
There could be pattern matching technique but i think its very much complex and i have no idea about it.
Thanks :)

Comment: length * degree of turn?

Comment: @Mike what should i do with length * degree ?
Longer the length grater the speed limit...

Comment: @Salmaan, Do u have access to the code ,could u help us by sample code if u have??Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could use the phone built-in accelerometer to measure acceleration force during turns.
This likely should not result higher than 0.8/1g (a F1 car reaches 5/6 g in turns to have an idea). The problem lies mainly in defining a threshold of acceptable g-force values, which should probably be defined by physically testing the sensor, and in the accuracy of the sensor itself. Indeed I firmly believe that the sensor must be mounted in some fixed position so to obtain consistent values.

Still, even if it seems a hard path to measure the "comfort" of a turn with this kind of device I think it would be the correct way since the g-force is the one giving us the feedback on how delicate was the turns.

This would solve also the problem of sharp turns during the smooth curves, where the g-force would be added to the one already in effect.
All of this is under the assumption that the device can continuously keep track of the g-force without resetting it after a period in which the variation detection occurred.